# Moving Emails to specific Outlook folders Using Access VBA

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, outlook, outlook-2013

I'm using Microsoft Office 2013 to set up an access database linked to an inbox in outlook. I'm having no issues setting up a linked table and manipulating the data within access.

What I want to do is move the email from one outlook folder/subfolder to another outlook folder/subfolder with VBA code within Access. In other words, I want to click on a button within Access and activate VBA coding that moves the email within Outlook.

Any tips on how to get started will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MailItem.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860683.aspx) and pass the target MAPIFolder object as the parameter.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I was able to use your answer to find some more information about writing the code I needed.
I also found that I needed to activate the outlook 15.0 object references by going to tools within the VBA window.